# How can I get the username of the person who initialised the file in ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows

How can I get the username of the person who initialised the file in ruby?

I'm using windows xp. and ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me in the end.

`require 'win32ole'

network=WIN32OLE.new("Wscript.Network")

user = network.username

puts user`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require 'etc'
File.stat("myfile").uid     ->      666 for example
puts 'my file owned by', Etc.getpwuid(uid).name
```

Comment: I don't get the 666 for example bit. sorry.... can you expand your reasoning? My file is called "tester.rb" thanks.

Comment: Also do I need to install etc separately or is it a standard part of ruby? thanks

Comment: This may not work in windows, it seems very *NIX dependent, I could be wrong though

Answer (score 0):

You can try `%x{ECHO USERNAME}.chomp` (I can't verify that this will work, as I cannot recall the variable in windows that is the username)